# How to hide tab bar in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

I just updated to Safari 15 and the new tab bar design actually makes me feel sick.

How can I hide the tabs? I'd rather use tab overview and keyboard tab navigation, and never have to see the tabs at all.

I already have "Always Show Toolbar in Fullscreen" unchecked, but sometimes I need to show the toolbar like when using my password manager, typing in a URL/search, using the menu bar.  I would like the tabs to not be shown even when the toolbar is.